# Load Unity3D scene on a Qt window

Tags: qt, unity-game-engine, qt5, qt5.5

Good evening,

In my current project i'm developing a simulator application based on a Qt 5.5 GUI. I want to simulate a 3d world generated by Unity based on orders to the engine from the Qt application.

In other words, how could I integrate Unity engine and an external application.

I've been trying initializing Unity with this code, but I'm unable to handle events on real time:

```
using UnityEditor;
class MyEditorScript
{
     static void PerformBuild ()
     {
         string[] scenes = { "Assets/MyScene.unity" };
         BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, ...);
      }
}
```

Application is under an early developement, so it is possible to change technologies at this moment, but Qt and Unity fits perfectly to the needs of my project